# How to write chess game in Solidity?

Tags: solidity

Hello I'm trying to learn solidity and found this example of chess which isn't completed, is there a way I can test it while I code with it, like see the progress of the game and the Knight moving?
here is the github repository: https://github.com/student1043/solidity

Answer (score 0):

There are a [few debuggers for solidity](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hosho.solidity-debugger) in vscode, yet most of them are not stable.

I suggest using [scaffold-eth](https://github.com/scaffold-eth/scaffold-eth), it's a project that uses react as a front-end, it generates a website with react that dynamically renders input fields, labels, and others related to your contract's variables and functions every time you deploy a new version of your contract, so you can interact with your contract and also see the changes live.

Yet, if you are new to solidity, and want to actually properly learn how to develop with solidity, I suggest taking a look at  [learnweb3](https://www.learnweb3.io/).